# How to scale down images in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a carousel which acts as a background image cover for my website kind of of like revolutionary slider in wordpress but not a plugin. Iam building it just for my static website. The problem is that some my images are different height and widths so the carousel doesn't adjust properly. for example img no. 1 is 2048*3072 px 2nd is 3072*2048 px and so on.I want to make my carousel height and width to be 100% like a cover image. when i do set min-width and height to be 100% and 100vh respectively the images gets cropped from the bottom. any help?     Here is my code

```
 <!--carousel-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
     <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="item active">
     <img class ="fill"src="img/msp_0409_3522.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

     <div class="item">
      <img class ="fill" src="img/msp_0406_1786.jpg" alt="Chania">
     </div>

     <div class="item">
      <img class ="fill" src="img/msp_1608_9566.jpg" alt="Flower">
     </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img class ="fill" src="img/msp_1605_6918.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-                                 slide="prev">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-    slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">    </span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
    </div>
```

css

```
  html,body{
  height:100%;
  }
  .carousel,.item,.active{
 height:100%;
   }
 .carousel-inner{
 height:100%;
 }
 .fill{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-position:center
  ;background-size:cover;
  }
```

Comment: `height` for body should be in pixel and then you can use `height: 100%`. Because it needs a reference height for `height: 100%` to work properly.

Comment: @Tumen_t not really. `height: 100%;` does not require a pixel value to inherit from, though it does require a height to be set on it's parent element (which can be of any unit) so it can figure out what 100% equals of a certain height. The OP has `height: 100%;` set on `html` _and_ `body`. This causes `body` to inherit from `html` from which `html` inherits from the viewport. Please reference [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ymern7h3/).

Answer (score 2):

In your code it looks like `.carousel-inner>.item>img` is overriding your fill class. In order to override the bootstrap property add an !important to your class.

```
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

You also do not need the `background-position` or `background-size` as they only  style background images

[Code Pen link](http://codepen.io/Elliot-Evans/pen/zZYNPW)

Comment: I tried this and the image didn't got cropped from the bottom but  the width doesn't remain 100% . the height works fine. any idea why

Answer (score 0):

you should use object-fit property.
You can try something like that:

```
.carousel-inner img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Answer (score 0):

for background image, you can use:

```
background-image: url("image.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```